# Не обновляется recycleview

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, recyclerview

Не обновляется данные при вызове метода onRefresh(). Данные остаются такими же какие были при первичном запуске приложения.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {


private AdapterMain adapter;
private Activity activity;
private RecyclerView gridView;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

public String status;

public Elements title;
public Elements content;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = this;

    swipeRefreshLayout = new SwipeRefreshLayout(activity);

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_red_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);

    gridView = new RecyclerView(activity);
    gridView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    gridView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    gridView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    swipeRefreshLayout.addView(gridView);
    getWindow().setContentView(swipeRefreshLayout);

    new NewThread().execute();

}

public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Item>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Item> doInBackground(String... arg) {
        ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.clear();
        int MAX_PAGE = 2;

        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_PAGE; i++) {
            final String url = "http://fratria.ru/cgi-bin/MainNews/index.cgi?line_id=0&page=" + i;
            Document doc;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                content = doc.select(".c1-post");
                status = "success";

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("Unknown Host Exception", "Network error", e);
                status = "myUnknownHostException";
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IO Exception", "Failed to load HTML", e);
                status = "myIOException";
                return null;
            }

            for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element contents : content) {
                Item item = new Item();

                // Заголовок
                title = contents.select("h2");
                item.setTitle(title.text());

                // Ссылка изображения
                try {
                    Elements link = contents.select(".c1-post-data img[src]");
                    String imageUrl = link.attr("src");
                    imageUrl = imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.indexOf("download")+8);
                    item.setImg("http://fratria.ru/download" + imageUrl);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Ссылка видео
                try {
                    Elements videoLink = contents.select(".c1-post-data iframe[src]");
                    String videoUrl = videoLink.attr("src");
                    item.setVideo(videoUrl);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Ссылка
                try {
                    Elements postLink = contents.select("h2 a[href^=/news/20]");
                    String postUrl = postLink.attr("href");
                    item.setLink("http://fratria.ru" + postUrl);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                data.add(item);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Item> data) {

        switch (status) {
            case "myUnknownHostException":
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Ошибка сетевого подключения. Проверьте соединение с интернетом и попробуйте снова.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                break;
            case "myIOException":
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Не известная ошибка. Загрузка прервана.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case "success":

                if(adapter == null) {
                    adapter = new AdapterMain(activity, data);
                    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }
}

private static long back_pressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis())
        super.onBackPressed();
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.back_message,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

protected void onDestroy(){

    super.onDestroy();

    if(isTaskRoot()){

        //clean the file cache with advance option
        long triggerSize = 6000000; //starts cleaning when cache size is larger than 3M
        long targetSize = 5000000;      //remove the least recently used files until cache size is less than 2M
        AQUtility.cleanCacheAsync(this, triggerSize, targetSize);
    }

}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new NewThread().execute();
}}
```

Адаптера кусок

```
public class AdapterMain extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterMain.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Item> data;
private AQuery aq;
private Activity activity;

public AdapterMain(Activity activity, ArrayList<Item> data) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.data = data;
    aq = new AQuery(activity);
}
```

Comment: Ну вот проинициализировался у вас адаптер в методе onPostExecute. И все. Больше вы ничего в нем не меняете же. data в doInBackground локальная же. И да. Вот за это(catch (Exception e)) обычно отрезают руки, ну да ладно.

Comment: Data локальная т.к. я создавю данные в doInBackground, возвращаю из метода и, получив в onPostExecute назначать в переменную активити. Сам адаптер, после инициализации, я не меняю, а вот данные хочу поменять т.е. уведомлять адаптер об изменении я должен в doInBackground? А для этого мне адаптер нужно инициализировать в onCreate?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил в адаптер методы: setData и clearData

```
public class AdapterMain extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterMain.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Item> data;
private AQuery aq;
private Activity activity;

public AdapterMain(Activity activity, ArrayList<Item> data) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.data = data;
    aq = new AQuery(activity);
}

public void setData(ArrayList<Item> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void clearData() {
    data.clear();
}
```

Переделал onPostExecute таким образом:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Item> data) {

    switch (status) {
        case "myUnknownHostException":
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Ошибка сетевого подключения. Проверьте соединение с интернетом и попробуйте снова.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            break;
        case "myIOException":
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Не известная ошибка. Загрузка прервана.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case "success":
            if(adapter == null) {
                adapter = new AdapterMain(activity, data);
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                adapter.clearData();
                adapter.setData(data);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(adapter == null) { 
    adapter = new AdapterMain(activity, data); 
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter); 
}  
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

Вот тут вы передаете в адаптер данные. Но если адаптер не `null` с данными в нем ничего не происходит.

Добавьте в своей реализации адаптера какую нибудь коллекцию из `Item` и с ней уже работайте. Т.е.

```
ArrayList<Item> data = adapter.getData();
data.clear();
...
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Внес изменения и все вроде работает. Теперь готов к отрыванию рук за catch (Exception e))